# Defining a namespace for Laravel 8 routes

Tags: php, laravel

Question about routing in Laravel 8.x

Now Im adding such lines in web.php file:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\FirstController;
use App\Http\Controllers\SecondController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ThirdController;
```

and then just working on `FirstController::class` etc.

Is it wrong to use just `namespace App\Http\Controllers;` instead of all `use` lines one after another x times at the beggining?

Thanks.

Comment: if you declare a namespace in that route file you would have to adjust the call to `Route` and the like but I suppose you could .... you could also alias that namespace and then reference the class via `Controllers\ThirdController::class` ... but i wouldn't be too worried about using `use` statements

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead, I would simply uncomment this line in `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` which will revert back to the Laravel <8 behavior of automatically prefixing route declarations in `'routes/web.php'` `'routes/api.php'`  with the `App\Http\Controllers` namespace.

```
/**
 * The controller namespace for the application.
 *
 * When present, controller route declarations will automatically be prefixed with this namespace.
 *
 * @var string|null
 */
 protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';
```

This commented out property might not be in your `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` if you created the project when v8 was first released, (seems it was removed then added back) if not, just add it and uncommnet, and make sure its used in the `boot` method  the prop and it'll work.

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->configureRateLimiting();

    $this->routes(function () {
        Route::prefix('api')
            ->middleware('api')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)           // make sure this is present
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

        Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)            // make sure this is present
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    });
}
```

Comment: only if the route groups in that provider are adding a namespace using that member variable, which is the actual important part

Comment: @lagbox indeed, updated to be more clear on that since it wasnt there in the initial release

Comment: yea i think there was enough backlash that they had to add this stuff back in and make it easier to change back to the old method; which should be the default in the first place with the option to "null" out that instead to get the current default behavior of 8

Comment: @lagbox 100% agreed! very odd to have axed it.

Comment: Though it solves the problem of repeatation, It defeates the purpose it was intended for. All the fuzz about the change was to help IDEs, You could jump to the definition directly, But enabling the old settings, you cannot jump to definition as its now a string. very handy feature IMHO. BUT, What I would like is namespace instead, so i don't have to repeat myself.