# How to fix ‘Target class does not exist’?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

How to fix ‘Target class does not exist’ in Laravel 8

I have applied all three of these fixes but I am still getting an error:

- Add the namespace back manually so you can use it as you did in Laravel 7.x and before
- Use the full namespace in your route files when using the string syntax
- Use the action syntax (recommended)

```
use App\Http\Controllers\EventController;
use App\Http\Controllers\FamilyController;
use App\Http\Controllers\HedgehogController;
use App\Http\Controllers\KeywordController;
use App\Http\Controllers\CommentController;
Route::get('/comments', [App\Http\Controllers\CommentController::class, 'index']);
```

Is there anything else I can do to fix this?

Comment: please provide the exact error message

Comment: Target class [App\Http\MemorysController] does not exist

Comment: well that class probably doesn't exist, since the Controllers should be in the `App\Http\Controllers` namespace  (but depends upon where you actually placed this file) ... also you are not showing anything here related to that class (like a route definition)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Target class controller does not exist - Laravel 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63807930/target-class-controller-does-not-exist-laravel-8)

Comment: are you going to follow up on your own question?

Comment: No, it did not help. It suggested using Fully Qualified Path (FQP).
I have used the FQP but still get DNE error. My controller's use section: namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Event;
use App\Models\Memorys; : class MemorysController extends Controller
. The routes: //memorys
Route::get('/memorys', [MemorysController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/memorys/create/{id}', [MemorysController::class,'create']);
Route::post('/memorys/', [MemorysController::class, 'store']);

Answer (score 2):

Please open your controller again then fix their namespace

then `php artisan config:cache`  do `php artisan config:clear before cache if necessary`

then reimport the Class then

```
php artisan route:cache
```

Comment: I will never underate these commands again, wasted hrs just for these.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same problem and i ran

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

this fixed it for me

Comment: This clears the events, views, cache, routes and config, so it clears anything that's cached! +1

Answer (score -1):

You have already import the namespace so use directly the controller like this

```
use App\Http\Controllers\CommentController;
Route::get('/comments', [CommentController::class, 'index']);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#the-default-route-files

Comment: good recommendation but both ways are creating the same string

Comment: I was just about to say that I have tried it with & without.

Answer (score -1):

Uncomment `protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';` in the RouteServiceProvider.

Found here:

[Defining a namespace for Laravel 8 routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64037500/defining-a-namespace-for-laravel-8-routes/64037683#64037683)

Answer (score -1):

It's a cache problem. You have to cache the routes. *DONT TOUCH YOUR CODES*

```
php artisan config:clear  <=====
php artisan route:cache  <=====
```